# tabla en Blade dentro de otra tabla filtro

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Tengo una tabla a la cual quiero filtrar sus resultados en el tabla que aparece en tabla.blade.php

```
  <table>       
    <tbody>
      @if($Clientes_contactos->count())  
      @foreach($Clientes_contactos as $Clientes_contactos1)

        <tr>
          <td>{{$Clientes_contactos1->clienteNombre}}</td>
        </tr> 

      @endforeach 

      @endif
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

asi me entrega todos los resultados pero quiero que me muestre los resultados donde el id se a mayor a 5 (por ejemplo pero yo busco algo como un "where" )

```
  <table>       
    <tbody>
      @if($Clientes_contactos->count())  
      @foreach($Clientes_contactos as $Clientes_contactos1)
      @if( $Clientes_contactos1->idClienteContactos > 5)
        <tr>
          <td>{{$Clientes_contactos1->clienteNombre}}</td>
        </tr> 
       @endif
      @endforeach 

      @endif
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: No tengo tiempo para redactar una respuesta en este momento, pero revisa esto: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-map

Comment: hola, perdon pero no entiendo lo de las coleciones y no estoy seguro la relacion

Answer (score 3):

Hay varias formas de resolver esto, aun que entiendo que lo más adecuado sería hacelo en el controlador cuando realizas la consulta, pues no tiene sentido a priori traer datos que no quieres mostrar o no vas a usar.

En el controlador puedes hacer algo como:

```
public function miMetodo() {
    $datos = MiModelo::where('campo', '>', 5)->get();

    return view('directorio.vista')
        ->with('Clientes_contactos ', $datos );
}
```

También sería posible hacerlo después de traer los datos trabajando la colección:

```
public function miMetodo() {
    $datos = MiModelo::all();

    // filtras aquellos registros que el campo id sea mayor a 5
    $filtered = $datos->filter(function ($value, $key) {
        return $value->id > 5;
    });


    return view('directorio.vista')
        ->with('Clientes_contactos ', $filtered);
}
```

Y como no, también se podría hacer en la vista con php, por ejemplo creando un condicional.

```
@foreach($Clientes_contactos as $Clientes_contactos1)

    @php
        // si el ide es menor continuamos con la siguiente iteracion del bucle
        if($Clientes_contactos1->id < 5)
            continue;
    @endphp

    <tr>
      <td>{{$Clientes_contactos1->clienteNombre}}</td>
    </tr> 

@endforeach
```